# What are the eigenvectors of this matrix and if these are the eigenvectors, why aren't they orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Given this matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\b & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$.

with $b \in \mathbb{R}$

I got the distinct eigenvalues to be $\pm \sqrt b$.

At the moment I get that they're:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \sqrt b \end{pmatrix}$
and
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ - \sqrt b \end{pmatrix}$

But these aren't orthogonal?

Why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the matrix is not symmetric.  A set of orthogonal eigenvectors that span the space is only guaranteed when the matrix is symmetric (or, in the complex case, when it is Hermitian.)